# FaceTime window jumps to unwanted position at start of call

Tags: window-manager, facetime, call

Running FaceTime 3.0 on MacOSX 10.10.1, there's an annoying behavior that I can't seem to change:

**When I first get an incoming call, the FaceTime window jumps to the far right of my rightmost display** (an external 30" Cinema display), **and can't be repositioned until the call is fully connected** (at which point I need to move it more than a yard to the left to center it with the camera in the MacBook Pro).

Why can't the window just stay where I put it?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem with FT audio. It goes to the upper right too and ends up covering my apps. Easy to move yes, but then it's not on top anymore and I have to dig around for it to end the call.

I poached this AppleScript and tied it to an Alfred Workflow

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "FaceTime"
tell application "FaceTime" to activate
tell front window to set position to {950, 696}
end tell
```

You could make your own trigger with normal script. Not great, but a quick workaround.